# SQL: order by how many rows there are (using COUNT?)

Tags: sql, count, sql-order-by, selected

For SMF, I'm making a roster for the members of my clan (please don't come with "You should ask SMF", because that is completely irrelevant; this is just contextual information).

I need it to select all members (from **smf_members**) and order it by how many permissions they have in **smf_permissions** (so the script can determine who is higher in rank).
You can retrieve how many permissions there are by using: `COUNT(permission) FROM smf_permissions.`

I am now using this SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(m.id_member), m.real_name, m.date_registered  
FROM smf_members AS m, smf_permissions AS p  
WHERE m.id_group=p.id_group  
ORDER BY COUNT(p.permission)
```

However, this only returns **one** row! How to return **several** rows?

Cheers,
Aart

Comment: I assume this is MySQL as all other RDBMSs would reject this AFAIK.

Comment: `distinct` is not a function and does not work on single columns. It always makes the whole row distinct. Your statement is roughly equivalent to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a `GROUP BY`. I've also rewritten with explicit `JOIN` syntax. You might need to change to `LEFT JOIN` if you want to include members with zero permissions.

```
SELECT m.id_member,
       m.real_name,
       m.date_registered,
       COUNT(p.permission) AS N
FROM   smf_members AS m
       JOIN smf_permissions AS p
         ON m.id_group = p.id_group
GROUP  BY m.id_member,
          m.real_name,
          m.date_registered
ORDER  BY COUNT(p.permission)
```

Comment: Ah, I see now that I forgot one thing: administrators have no permissions (because they have all - SMF logic xD). I would like to have them on top, though.

Comment: You need a `LEFT JOIN` and `ORDER  BY CASE WHEN COUNT(p.permission) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC, COUNT(p.permission) DESC`

Comment: One last thing: I want to divide users in staff and non-staff. The staff has more permissions than 145. I thought I could simply add: `WHERE COUNT(p.permission) > 145` after the `LEFT JOIN ON`. However, this returns no rows.. :(

Comment: If there is no flag in the users table that you can use in a `WHERE` clause then you would need `HAVING COUNT(p.permission) > 145`

Comment: I added that after the `GROUP BY`, but now I'm having troubles with the administrators that have no permissions again. `HAVING COUNT(p.permission) > 145 OR COUNT(p.permission) = 0` doesn't work and I can't seem to find a substitute for it.

Comment: Wait! It does work!
`HAVING COUNT(p.permission) > 145 OR COUNT(p.permission) = 0`
My bad, sorry.